# Sphinx and PHP integration. Low performance

Tags: php, sphinx

I have the following situation: DB ~ 116G ~800 mln. rows with next structure:

```
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `key` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `key` (`key`(255)) USING BTREE
```

The second column can contain Russian/English letters and words, digits, and special characters like #, %, \ etc.
I want organize search only by Russian/English characters and digits.

Sphinx configuration:

```
source keywords
{
    sql_query_pre       = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query       = \
        SELECT * \
        FROM keywords
    sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM keywords WHERE id=$id
}
index keywords
{
    source          = keywords
    docinfo         = extern
    dict            = keywords
    mlock           = 0
    min_stemming_len    = 1
    min_word_len        = 1
    charset_type        = utf-8
    charset_table = U+0030..U+0039, U+0041..U+005A, U+0061..U+007A, U+0410..U+044F
    ignore_chars        = U+0021..U+0029, U+003A..U+0040, U+005B..U+0060, U+007B..U+040F, U+0450..U+2FFFF
    min_prefix_len      = 1
    enable_star = 1
    html_strip      = 0
}

indexer
{
    mem_limit       = 1024M
}

searchd
{
    client_timeout      = 300
    max_children        = 30
    max_matches     = 1000000
    max_packet_size     = 8M
    max_batch_queries   = 32
}
```

PHP configuration:

```
    $oCl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_PHRASE);

    $oCl->SetLimits(0, $iLimit);

    $sQueryForSphinx = implode('* ', explode(' ', $oCl->EscapeString($sQuery))) . '*';

    $aResult = $oCl->Query('" ' . $sQueryForSphinx . ' "');
```

I want to provide next search algorithm:
In $Query i have user data. 
There could be only words which contain Russian/English characters and digits separated by space. 
Min length of word is 1. Minimum count of word is 1, maximum is 3.
I want to find all keys in database which contain these words in the same order as user typed their.  Also to every word can contains additional symbols at the end of word.

Example:
User typed: tes test test1:
Should return keys which contain next phrases: "tes test test1", "test test1 test12", "test1 test12 test124", etc.

This configuration works perfectly with words of length greater than 4 symbols. Time of search less than 5 sec.

My problem is that when I type a phrase that contains one or more words of length less than 4 symbols (for example "te t test") sphinx works very slowly,  about 1 minute or more.

Any suggestion how I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `dict=crc`, should perform MUCH better for these queries. (at the expense of slower indexing, and a much bigger index)

`dict=keywords` indexes can be VERY slow for short word searches. Because of the 'exploding prefixes' issue.

dict=keywords has only recently been made the default mode, so its performance is still not well understood. 
See the comments here:
http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2013/09/11/deprecations-and-changes-in-the-2-2-series/
The index I talking about is small - its for autocomplete, but was 100x performance difference.

Comment: out of interest, what sort of performance do you get now? eg 4 letter words got 5 seconds with dict=keywords, how about the same query with dict=crc

Comment: Hi,
With three russian single letters "м н т" ~ 12 sec, with one letter "1" for example ~ 2 sec. When i try to find phrases with words of lenght great then 2 symbols in 99% time is less then 1 sec(avg. 0.4 sec) in case with $iMaxResults = 1000.  For me it works perfectly, as i was expected. 
Now data folder is ~ 109GB, where keywords.spd ~ 103GB and keywords.serp ~2 GB.